# How to show the scheduled cron to the user - Celery scheduler?

Tags: celery, scheduled-tasks, celerybeat

I have a django app where users can schedule to run their tasks every week/month. I am storing this as a `CrontabSchedule` in django_celery_beat. Now, I would like to show the user his schedule (like task will run every saturday at 12AM -human readable format). How can I do this when the crontab is TZ aware?

And the user could be in different timezone than the timezone of the `TZ aware crontab` in django_celery_beat.

E.g. The user has set the schedule to run a task at 3.30AM in Asia/Hong_Kong timezone. But the user is at Berlin now. I want to display this schedule (3.30AM Asia/Hong_Kong) in human-readable format to the user according to his timezone.